# Node.js ECONNREFUSED when trying to install packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm working the learnyounode tutorial to learn node.js. I'm getting an error any time I try install a package.

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-c9
npm ERR! argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/npm" "install" "through2-map" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.5
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:15443
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:15443]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '127.0.0.1',
npm ERR!   port: 15443 }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/workspace/npm-debug.log
```

I also did npm config ls to see if there was anything out of the ordinary with my configuration but really I don't know what I'm looking for. Can someone help me figure out how to fix this error so that I can install packages.

```
; cli configs
user-agent = "npm/3.7.5 node/v4.1.1 linux x64"

; userconfig /home/ubuntu/.config/how-to-npm/npmrc
//localhost:15443/:always-auth = false
//localhost:15443/:email = "rawledjuglal@gmail.com"
//localhost:15443/:username = "rawlejuglal"

; node bin location = /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/node
; cwd = /home/ubuntu/workspace
; HOME = /home/ubuntu
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Answer (score 7):

Set your NPM registry back to registry.npmjs.org:

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 1):

your npmrc file is trying to send you to a registry host on localhost:15443, delete those three lines with // from your npmrc file and try npm installing again. This should send you to the npm registry, where that package exists.

Comment: Thanks, since I'm new to this node.js is there a command to type to delete those items? or where do I search to find the npmrc file?

Comment: the file should be located ~/.npmrc

Answer (score 0):

I also fetch is problem. I hope following information may help someone else like me.

For me, the reason was **.npmrc** where registry was set to http://localhost:15443/

**.npmrc** is one of sources from where **npm** gets its config settings. You will get more information about **.npmrc** file from 
 [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc)

### How I troubleshoot

I have used command `npm config ls -l` that show npm configuration list where I found that registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ is overridden. 
Part of my configuration

```
; project config /home/sumon/projects/codecamp-node/.npmrc
registry = "http://localhost:15443/"
userconfig = "/home/sumon/.config/how-to-npm/npmrc"

; userconfig /home/sumon/.config/how-to-npm/npmrc
//localhost:15443/:always-auth = false
//localhost:15443/:email = "hasanuzzaman.sumon@gmail.com"
//localhost:15443/:username = "engr.hasanuzzaman"
; registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/" (overridden)
```

From above you will see that **project config** indicating a `.npmrc` that is on my project's root folder.

In unix system file that start with **.** are hidden file. To see hidden file on unix you can use `ctl+h` of `ls -a` from terminal.

### How to solve this problem

1. Remove `registry = http://localhost:15443/` from `.npmrc` file if you don't need this
2. set registry option like following 
   `npm install your_package --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org`

Answer (score -1):

It seems require init once again:

1. Go to package directory (where package.json  is located)
2. Run: npm init
3. Answer all questions in command line
4. Go to browser and go 127.0.0.1:15443
5. As successful result should get: { error: "missing" }