# npm install package name connects to 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I am working in Node JS. My problem is, if I am trying to install any package or if I am trying for "`npm install`" it gives me following error.[image]

I dont know whats happening if I am trying to install any package. Please help me in this I am facing very serious issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check for solutions in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775058/node-js-econnrefused-when-trying-to-install-packages

Comment: @Ashok JayaPrakash Thanks a lot. I have spent my enitre day to solve this issue. Finally its solved. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Ashok JayaPrakash Can you tell me that what will be the possibility that registry has been set to http://localhost:3000/. Because I dont know how its been set.

Comment: Not sure about your case. One possiblity is when  npm-shrinkwrap.json is pointed to localhost, this kind of error will happen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js ECONNREFUSED when trying to install packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775058/node-js-econnrefused-when-trying-to-install-packages)

Comment: @Ashok JayaPrakash Okay. Thanks buddy.